# react native TypeError: this.setState is not a function.'this.setState' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am fetching json from an open source api. I want to store it as a state. Not able to store json data in a state. I need to use this json data to match a city with one of the cities in the json. I need to store it in the state. Would be very useful. Please do help!

***Constructor Part***

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    location: null,
    loading: false,
    userLatitude: null,
    userLongitude: null,
    userCity: null,

    covidZones: []

  }

  this._requestLocation = this._requestLocation.bind(this)
  this.getZone = this.getZone.bind(this)

}
```

***Function Part***

```js
getZone() {
  axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/zones.json')
    .then(function(response) {

      this.setState({
        covidZones: response.data.zones
      })

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    })
    .finally(function() {
      // always executed
    })
}
```

***Render Part***

```
render() {
    const { location, loading } = this.state;

    return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    disabled={loading}
                    title="Get Location"
                    onPress={this._requestLocation}
                />

                <Text>{this.state.userCity}</Text>

                {this.getZone()} // calling the function, right here


                {loading ? (
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                ) : null}
                {location ? (
                    <Text>
                        {JSON.stringify(location, 0, 2)}
                    </Text>
                ) : null}
            </View>
        )
}
```

Comment: You should run your data-fetching operations in `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook. Refer here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling an api `{this.getZone()}` in the `render` function. This, I'm afraid, will lead to an infinite loop as after each of those calls, `setState` will be triggered which in turn will call the `render` function.

To fix this:
 1. Remove `{this.getZone()}` from `render` method.
 2. Put this in `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount(){
this.getZone()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared an example for your using `reactjs`. Same technic should be followed in `react-native`. Please follow this example:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ZoneListPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            location: null,
            loading: false,
            userLatitude: null,
            userLongitude: null,
            userCity: null,
            covidZones: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
            covidZones: null
        });
        fetch("https://api.covid19india.org/zones.json")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    console.log(result.zones, 'zones');
                    this.setState({
                        loading: false,
                        covidZones: result.zones
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <ul>
                    {
                        this.state.covidZones ? this.state.covidZones.map((zone, index) =>
                                <div key={index}>
                                    <div key={index}> District: <span key={index}>{zone.district}</span></div>
                                    <div key={index}> District Code: <span key={index}>{zone.districtcode}</span></div>
                                    <div key={index}> Last Updated: <span key={index}>{zone.lastupdated}</span></div>
                                    <div key={index}> Source: <a key={index} href={zone.source}>source</a></div>
                                    <div key={index}> State: <span key={index}>{zone.state}</span></div>
                                    <div key={index}> State Code: <span key={index}>{zone.statecode}</span></div>
                                    <div key={index}> Zone: <span key={index}>{zone.zone}</span></div>
                                    <hr/>
                                </div>)
                            :
                            null
                    }
                </ul>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

**Here is image that comes in output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see an error that says `setState is not a function` is, in your fetch's `.then` function `this` will no longer refer to the component. You have to bind `this` with an arrow function, you can fix the `setState` error like this:

```
 axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/zones.json')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ covidZones: response.data.zones })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(()=> {
                // always executed
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

there are 3 different solution for you.

getZone() {

```
    axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/zones.json')
        .then((response)=> {

            this.setState({ covidZones: response.data.zones })

        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(()=> {
            // always executed
        })
}
```

or

```
var self = this;

axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/zones.json')
        .then(function (response) {

            self.setState({ covidZones: response.data.zones })

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(function () {
            // always executed
        })
```

or

```
axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/zones.json')
            .then(function (response) {

                this.setState({ covidZones: response.data.zones })

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(function () {
                // always executed
            }).bind(this));
```